# Flush size when using kafka-connect-transform-archive with HdfsSinkConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have  data in a Kafka topic which I want to preserve on my data lake.

Before worrying about the keys, I was able to save the Avro values in files on the datalake using HdfsSinkConnector. The number of message values in each file was determined by the "flush.size" property of the HdfsSinkConnector.

All good. Next I wanted to preserve the keys as well. To do this I used the kafka-connect-transform-archive which wraps the String key and Avro value into a new Avro schema.

This works great ... except that the flush.size for the HdfsSinkConnector is now being ignored. Each file saved in the data lake has exactly 1 message only.

So, the two cases are 1) save values only, with the number of values in each file determined by the flush.size and 2) save keys and values with each file containing exactly one message and flush.size being ignored.

The only difference between the two situations is the configuration for the HdfsSinkConnector which specifies the archive transform.

```
"transforms": "tran",
"transforms.tran.type": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.archive.Archive"
```

Does the kafka-connect-transform-archive ignore flush size by design, or is there some additional configuration that I need in order to be able to save multiple key, value messages per file on the data lake?

Comment: The transform happens before each message reaches HDFS Connect, so no property is "ignored". I have noticed that files are flushed when there are different schema versions being produced at the same time into the topic. So what might be happening is that HDFS connect thinks it wants to write "just value" schema, then gets a record of "key+value", then clears the buffer and immediately writes the file...

Comment: Thank you for the response, but can you explain it again please, it confuses me (sorry). Maybe I have misunderstood (always possible) but your second sentence is saying that we might be writing different schemas to the topic (so something is going wrong before we start using Kafka Connect), and the third sentence seems to imply that this is a pure HDFS connect issue related to wanting to write key-value schemas, when it is expecting just the value schema. What have I got wrong here?

Comment: I think you understood fine. I've only tested the archive transform with S3 Connect. I didn't look into how often it flushed. But we ultimately didn't use it and just copied the key (which are mostly strings for us) directly into the message value during producing

Comment: Would you say at the moment that there is no available solution to do what I want to do?

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. It'd require someone to debug the source code of the HDFS connector to see why it's writing only one record at a time

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when using kafka gcs sink connector.

In com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.archive.Archive code, a new Schema is created per message.

```
private R applyWithSchema(R r) {
final Schema schema = SchemaBuilder.struct()
    .name("com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.archive.Storage")
    .field("key", r.keySchema())
    .field("value", r.valueSchema())
    .field("topic", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
    .field("timestamp", Schema.INT64_SCHEMA);
Struct value = new Struct(schema)
    .put("key", r.key())
    .put("value", r.value())
    .put("topic", r.topic())
    .put("timestamp", r.timestamp());
return r.newRecord(r.topic(), r.kafkaPartition(), null, null, schema, value, r.timestamp());
```

}

If you look at kafka transform InsertField$Value method, you will see that it use a SynchronizedCache in order to retreive the same schema every time.

https://github.com/axbaretto/kafka/blob/ba633e40ea77f28d8f385c7a92ec9601e218fb5b/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/InsertField.java#L170

So, you just need to create a schema (outside the apply function) or use the same SynchronizedCache code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. At the time we got around this by reformatting our input data so that the key was included in the value. that way, no transformation was required. :man_shrugging_emoji: