# Include the key from a Kafka message with a connect sink HDFS connector

Tags: apache-kafka, hdfs, transformation, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm using the Kafka connect HDFS sink connector to write to HDFS from kafka, it is working fine. My messages look like this:

```
key: my-key
value: {
"name": "helen"
}
```

My use case is that in need to append the keys of my message to the events i send to HDFS.

The problem is that the key doesn't appear in the value payload so that i cannot use:

```
"partitioner.class": 
"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.FieldPartitioner", 
"partition.field.name": "key",
```

My question is how can I add the key to the message I send to the HDFS or how can i partioned based on the key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Out of the box, you can't (same goes for S3 Connect), just based on the way the code is written, not a limitation of the Connect framework</strike>

**Edit** - For the S3 sink, at least, I think there is now a property to include the keys

At the very least, you would need to build and add this SMT to your Connect workers, which will "move" the key, topic, and partition all over into the "value" of the Connect record before writing to storage

https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive

Comment: This is a solution for S3 and it helps, but or sink is HDFS.

Comment: The transform works for any sink connector. Ignore the description

Comment: ok,  thanks. The description also speaks about org.apache.kafka.some.SourceConnector when what I need here is org.apache.kafka.some.SinkConnector

Comment: The transform returns a SinkRecord , I'm not sure where you're seeing anything about sources

Comment: The connector class of https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive#distributed-example is a SourceConnector instead a SinkConnector

Comment: Uh, no... That is just bad documentation, and not even a valid connector name. The only relevant property of that whole project is the `com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.archive.Archive`, which has nothing to do with sources or sinks, but assumes data is coming from Kafka, like I said

Comment: but it is a connector or a transformation that we will use inside a connector?

Comment: The later. You add `transforms` property to the HDFS sink connector config

Comment: @Dipperman You might want to document your solution to help this person out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55865349/flush-size-when-using-kafka-connect-transform-archive-with-hdfssinkconnector